# Google Cloud SDK installer fails to complete component installation on Windows

Tags: php, sdk, installation, google-cloud-storage

I downloaded it from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows).

[image]

gives me error:
[image]

Error Log:

> Output folder: C:\Users\Info 7\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK
>   Downloading Google Cloud SDK core. Extracting Google Cloud SDK core.
>   Create Google Cloud SDK bat file: C:\Users\Info
>   7\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\cloud_env.bat Installing components.
>   Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK! ERROR: (gcloud.components.update)
>   Failed to fetch component listing from server. Check your network
>   settings and try again. This will install all the core command line
>   tools necessary for working with the Google Cloud Platform. Failed to
>   install.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? if so, are you behind a proxy? Are you restricting access to some ports in your firewall? Did you try installing it as Administrator?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue tonight, and I was able to get by the error message by performing the following:

1. Install Python 2.7
2. Add Python install directory to PATH (my case: c:\Python27)
3. Add System Variable CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to be python.exe in the Python install directory (my case: c:\Python27\python.exe)
4. Install Google Cloud SDK

Answer (score 2):

I had set the environment variable `HTTPS_PROXY` and forgotten about it. I just had to remove it to get this to work.

I guess you may have the opposite issue if you're behind a proxy so make sure you set it (or maybe `HTTP_PROXY`) to configure it.